# ReadFile() reads less bytes than the specified value in its argument

Tags: c++, c, winapi, serial-port, readfile

I have this code for reading bytes from serial port , but with client's device the message `"No enough information"`
is displayed and he says there is enough information in the serial port but this message 
is displayed.

```
int SuccessfulRead(unsigned char * s , DWORD bytesRead){

    if( bytesRead == 2 ){
        //...
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

//Reading

int i=1 , breakWhile=0 ;
while(!breakWhile)
{
DWORD dwRead;
BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE; //overlapped
OVERLAPPED osReader = {0};
unsigned char lpBuf[2];

osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
if (osReader.hEvent == NULL){
MessageBox( NULL , L"Unable to create event" , L"Error" , MB_OK);
breakWhile=1;
}
if (!fWaitingOnRead) {
   // Issue read operation.
   if (!ReadFile(hPort2, lpBuf, 2, &dwRead,&osReader)) {
       if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING){     
           MessageBox(NULL , L"Error in communication" , L"ERROR" , MB_OK);
           break;
       }
       else
           fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
   }
   else {
       // read completed immediately
       int res=SuccessfulRead(lpBuf,dwRead);
       if( !res){
           MessageBox(NULL , L"No enough information" , L"" , MB_OK);
           break;
       }
   }
}



#define READ_TIMEOUT   2000      // milliseconds
DWORD dwRes=0;
if (fWaitingOnRead) {
dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osReader.hEvent,READ_TIMEOUT);
switch(dwRes)
{
    // Read completed.
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:{
        if (!GetOverlappedResult(hPort2, &osReader, &dwRead,FALSE))
            MessageBox(NULL , L"Error in GetOverlappedResult" , L"Error" , MB_OK);

        else{
            // Read completed successfully.
            int res=SuccessfulRead(lpBuf,dwRead);
            if(!res){//less than two bytes read that is one byte readed
            MessageBox(NULL , L"No enough information" , L"" , MB_OK);
            breakWhile=1;//exit loop
            }
        //Reset flag so that another opertion can be issued.
        fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
                     }
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        if( i==1){//failed in first try
            MessageBox(NULL , L"There is no data please try again", L"" , MB_OK);
        }


        breakWhile=1;//exit loop

        break;
                       }
}
                  }
CloseHandle(osReader.hEvent);
i++;
}
```

It must read 2 bytes every time because of `ReadFile(hPort2, lpBuf, 2, &dwRead,&osReader)` , but it reads 1 byte in first time so it means there is not more than 1 byte in the serial port.
But seems like `code vision` reads that bytes and why this program only reads 1 byte when there is more than 2 bytes ? when in `ReadFile()` the bytes to read is 2.

Why does not it work and how to make it work?

Can it be related to `timeout` value?

Thanks

Comment: Show a [mcve]. Don't just dump all of your code.

Comment: @IInspectable I removed the parts that dont relate to this problem but i think the parts that i didnt remove relate to problem and i cant figure out what is wrong. please dont downvote

Comment: The brace at the end of `case WAIT_OBJECT_0:{` is mis-matched.  A consistent and conventional indentation and alignment style would make that obvious, and if you are going to ask others to review your code it is a good idea to make it as readable as possible in any case.  This is a mess.

Comment: @ Clifford You are right im sorry thats because of frequent edits that i made. Im editing

Comment: You _must_ copy and paste exactly the code that is generating the error, not edit it in the question, otherwise how can we rely on the fact that it even exhibits the problem?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This does not just only help us to read and understand your code but also yourself to better see what you are doing, trust me. As it stands the code is not very readable.

Comment: @Clifford By editing i mean removing the parts that are not necessary for this question

Comment: The code from `//Reading` onward is not inside a function body - if that is a separate  code fragment, you should separate it from `SuccessfulRead()` otherwise it is not valid as a single block of code.

Comment: Yes, it was wrong before that edit.  If you don't know what is wron, you are hardly qualified to determine what is irrelevant.  Besides it is still mismatched in you edit.

Comment: @ Clifford  thanks for taking your time here. Im trying to indent it properly so that others can review it

Comment: Format it in the _real_ code, compile and run it to make sure it still exhibits the same problem, then post it - _do not_ try to fix it in the question.  Any decent code editor will format it for you, but may be confused by your mixture of brace positioning style.  There is a good chance that in fixing the formatting you will discover your error.

Comment: @ Clifford it is compiled and worked for me the problem is that it does not work in client's device. Thats why i posted the question here

Comment: You miss my point; _you_ may have code that compiles, but that is not the code you have posted.  You have to post the code that is failing, not something just _similar_ (and invalid).  Have you ever considered stepping the code in a debugger - the error will be come rather obvious I think.

Comment: _"When reading from a communications device, the behavior of ReadFile is determined by the current communication time-out as set and retrieved by using the SetCommTimeouts and GetCommTimeouts functions. Unpredictable results can occur if you fail to set the time-out values. For more information about communication time-outs, see COMMTIMEOUTS."_ [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile)

Comment: @Daniel Sęk Thanks . Ive set the values for time-out to 3 seconds. Can it be possible to be incompatible with the device? How can i find the values to meet the device's requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
        int res=SuccessfulRead(lpBuf,dwRead);
        if(!res){//less than two bytes read that is one byte readed
```

the comment suggests that you are expecting >= two bytes, but `SuccessfulRead()` only returns non-zero when *exactly* two bytes are read:

```
if( bytesRead == 2 ){ // EXACTLY two bytes!!!
    //...
    return 1;
}
```

You need:

```
if( bytesRead <= 2 ){ // AT LEAST two bytes
...
```

for the comment to be correct.